# Netbeans could not find or load main class

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a project name JavaApplication3 and I place it in `D:\\`. But when I build project, the compiler said :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.
```

But when I move my project to `C:\\User\\Administrator` it works.

**What should I do to place my project to another place but it's still working?**

Comment: Run As Administrator may help.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Netbeans with the following specs:

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 (Build 201107282000)
Java: 1.7.0_09; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 23.5-b02
System: Windows XP version 5.1 running on x86; Cp1252; en_US (nb)

One can also turn off the option to automatically compile on save, then open the file you wish to run, make some tiny edit, save and recompile it.

Also I've found its a good practice to erase/delete all the temp files netbeans creates also automatically.  On my system these are located in C:\temp

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the project node > Project Properties > Run > Select main class.

[MANIFEST.MF](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/manifest.html) file describes which class to consider as main class.